# Invalid Syntax Error when creating estimator in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to use Tensorflow in a Colab Notebook to train identically structured neural networks with varying sizes of randomly chosen training examples from the MNIST data set. I have previously been successful in training neural networks in a similar fashion several times, but this time I am receiving an Invalid Syntax error that I have not been able to correct. The error appears for the following line of code:

`mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn)`

I have used this same line of code successfully in a different notebook, and I have not been able to recognize any problems with the syntax (it's from the Tensorflow documentation found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers)

The code I am trying to execute can be found below (but I have omitted the definition of cnn_model_fn for the sake of brevity).

```
#Initialize list to hold all of the accuracy data
all_accuracies = []

#For each training set group
for group_number in range(len(train_set_sizes)):

  #For each ANN in training set group
  for i in range(num_ANNs):

    #Initialize group_accuracies list
    group_accuracies = []

    #--------------Generate a training set--------------------------------

    #Initialize train_set lists
    train_set_examples = []
    train_set_labels = []

    #randomly select indices to pull train set examples
    example_select_indices = np.random.randint(0,55000,size=train_set_sizes[group_number])

    #For number of images in the appropriate training set group
    for j in range(train_set_sizes[group_number]):

      random_index = example_select_indices[j]
      train_set_examples = np.asarray(train_set_examples.append(train_images[random_index]))
      train_set_labels = np.asarray(train_set_labels.append(train_labels[random_index])

    # Create the MNIST Estimator
    mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn)

    # Train the CNN model
    mnist_classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,steps=train_steps)

    # Evaluate the models and print results
    eval_result = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
    print("Group Number ",group_number+1,", ANN #",i+1," Accuracy: ",eval_result," %")

    #Record ANN accuracy
    group_accuracies.append(eval_result)

#record group accuracies in all_accuracies
all_accuracies.append(group_accuracies)
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for why this error might be occurring?

Thank you!

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on the previous line

Comment: Oh dear, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you kindly for pointing this out, and my apologies for the trivial question!